# Prevent page reload when using dynamic filters Power bi /Anuglar

Tags: angular, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I integrated a power bi report in an angular page however I created a navbar for this same report with filters and I want it to be fixed when I scroll the page.
It worked however when I choose an item in a filter the page reloads.

Is there a way to change in the same page without reloading it? If there is no solution is there a time to make the loading invisible in angular until the report is displayed directly?

I used a query like that : "https://app.powerbi.com/reportID&filter=satcli_detail/Produit eq 'IR'"

Thanks

Comment: You have to use to API to achieve that, which means you will have to change the way you embed the report - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters

Comment: this is exactly what i need thank you very much. However do you have a concrete example code to help me?

Comment: [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core), [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html)